# Multicontainer Azure WebApp not working with Managed Identity

Tags: c#, azure, docker-compose, azure-keyvault

**Scenario/repro**

I have multicontainer (tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container)) azure web app. I assigned System Assigned identity to my web app. There are two containers in my docker compose:

- Net core WebApi container
- Antivirus ClamAv container

Everything had worked fine (my API is using antivirus to scan files) till the moment I add key vault Configuration provider with Managed Identity for Azure resources ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources)). This works perfectly with my standard web apps on linux.

```
// Program.cs
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
  if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
  {
    var builtConfig = config.Build();
    var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri($"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
    new DefaultAzureCredential());
    config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
  }
})
```

**Problem**
My API returns 503 status code.
It seems that I need to do some extra configuration to make it work with Docker compose.

```
EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
2021-06-14T11:42:46.912167603Z - ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No Managed Identity endpoint found.
2021-06-14T11:42:46.912175503Z - Operating system Linux 5.4.0-1031-azure #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 6 10:03:22 UTC 2020 isn't supported.
2021-06-14T11:42:46.912183204Z - Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account.
2021-06-14T11:42:46.912190304Z - Azure CLI not installed
2021-06-14T11:42:46.912197204Z - PowerShell is not installed.
2021-06-14T11:42:46.912205004Z ---> System.AggregateException: Multiple exceptions were encountered 
...
Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
...
Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: Operating system Linux 5.4.0-1031-azure #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 6 10:03:22 UTC 2020 isn't supported.
```

It seems that this feature is not fully supported. Any idea how to use key vault proivder in such scenario?

Comment: Please confirm if you have granted `get` and `list` permissions to the Managed Identity on the key vault secret resources. Here is the snippet from the tutorial you mentioned in your post:

`az keyvault set-policy --name {KEY VAULT NAME} --object-id {OBJECT ID} --secret-permissions get list
`

Comment: Yes I did. As I mentioned this works perfectly with my standard web apps. The problem is with docker compose apps. Exception details says that error is in web app environment.

Comment: Check if this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817337/azure-keyvault-azure-identity-credentialunavailableexception-defaultazurecrede

Comment: Web app environment set this variables on its own. It is not visible by user e.g. in Kudu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed identities are not supported in multicontainer apps. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/118045/are-managed-identities-for-multi-container-webapps.html